# Reading gzip file with pandas doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gzip

I've trambled into a small issue with the pandas `pd.read_csv` function:

I've downloaded very large amounts of data in the form of csv.gzip files, and i'd rather let them compressed on my computer, because of the tremendous amount of space they take.

I want to load them into python, to do so, I've been using the usual `pd.read_csv` function, adding the `compression='gzip'` argument, while pandas manages to read the csv with the correct amount of columns and the correct index length, the data is complety buggy:

```
tick = pd.read_csv("D:\Finance python\Data\EUR_USD\Tick\\2015\\1.csv.gz",compression='gzip')

tick.head()
Out[30]: 
    D  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0 NaN         NaN         NaN
1 NaN         NaN         NaN
2 NaN         NaN         NaN
3 NaN         NaN         NaN
4 NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Would anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong when I try to read the file?

Pandas clearly recognizes that the data is in gzip form, but I have no idea of why it doesn't manages to extract it correctly.^

Thanks

**The data that I'm trying to read:** https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look into the original csv file shows that it contains null characters `^@` which is why `pandas` cannot parse it correctly

You can cleanup those characaters by using shell command

```
gzip -dc 1.csv.gz | tr -d '\0' | gzip > 1_clean.csv.gz
```

- `gzip -dc` decompresses the file into stdout
- `tr -d '\0'` deletes the null characters
- `gzip` compresses it back to a gzipped file

After that `pandas` should be able to read it correctly

---

**UPDATE**

In case when you don't have access to shell, you can still use python to do the trick, although it would be slower

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('1.csv.gz', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

with gzip.open('1_clean.csv.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
However, I'm sorry I don't understand the syntax that you're using, and it doesn't work when I paste it in python.
But I think that I understood the issue, shall I change it using gzip and the csv module, or is there a better and simpler syntax like the one you used to make it work?

Comment: @Erlinska Sorry to mention, that is actually a shell command which you can type it on a terminal to execute on Unix-like systems (Linux, Mac). If you are on Windows, you can either install `Windows Subsystem for Linux` or use another python script to replace those null characters

Comment: I'm using windows, that's why I didn't understand it, thank you very much

Comment: @Erlinska Just made an update using pure python to remove those null characters in case you don't have access to shell